# Scrapy XPath syntax to extract partial data from a string

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to scrapping and scrapy, and I am stuck on the syntax for retrieving partial data from a html page. I need to get the price information from the sample code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="google-play-app" content="app-id=com.move.realtor">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#d92228">
    <meta name="description" content="View 2 photos of this 0 bed, 1 bath, 227 Sq. Ft. condo/townhome/row home/co-op at 4130 Collins Ave Unit 708, Miami Beach, FL 33140 on sale now for $160,000."/>
```

I need to extract 160,000

I understand how to extract the entire string, but I am stuck on how to extract the price information after the dollar sign.

```
def parse(self, response):
        #hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        #sites = hxs.select('//div/li/div/a/@href')
        sites = response.xpath('//head')
        items =  []
        for site in sites: 

            item = RealtorItem()
            item['description'] = site.xpath('meta[@name="description"]/@content').extract()
```

This code extracts the entire string and places it in Items, I think I have to split the string and only store the information after the dollar sign? Can I do it using regex ? Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

The code for finding the content might be made somewhat shorter using something along these lines (but not exactly this).

```
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> selector = Selector(text=fragment)
>>> content = selector.xpath('.//meta[starts-with(@content,"View 2")]/@content').extract()[0]
>>> content
'View 2 photos of this 0 bed, 1 bath, 227 Sq. Ft. condo/townhome/row home/co-op at 4130 Collins Ave Unit 708, Miami Beach, FL 33140 on sale now for $160,000.'
```

Once you have that content you can indeed isolate the price using a regex.

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.search(r'\$([0-9,.]+)', content)
>>> m.groups()
('160,000.',)
```

But my question was, how would you identify the correct `meta` in the first place? These elements with the `description`/`content` combination are extremely common. You could consider reducing the number of them to check for price using code like this, which looks for dollar symbols.

```
>>> which_meta = selector.xpath('.//meta[contains(@content,"$")]')
>>> which_meta
[<Selector xpath='.//meta[contains(@content,"$")]' data='<meta name="description" content="View 2'>]
```